# Safari vs Chrome : span inside button tag gets clipped in Safari

Tags: html, css, macos, google-chrome, safari

This is the markup :

```
<div class="resSnip">
      <button>
        <div>
          <div class="reslogo">
          <span class="source">Some text</span>
          </div>
          <p class="heading ng-binding">Some other text
          </p>
        </div>
      </button>
    </div>
```

This is the css :

```
.resSnip{
  width: 65%;
  max-width: 770px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-left: 77px;
}

.reslogo{
//float: left;
margin: 0 20px 0 -57px;
}
```

This is how it looks on Chrome v59.0.3071.115 :
[image: Chrome]

This is how it looks on Safari Version 10.0.3 :
[image: Safari]

This only seems to happen with `button` . 
Also, even with button, If i just change the markup to this :

```
<div class="resSnip">
          <button>
            <div style="position:relative">
              <div class="reslogo">
              <span class="source">Some text</span>
              </div>
              <p class="heading ng-binding">Some other text
              </p>
            </div>
          </button>
        </div>
```

It seems to render correctly. 
Explanations ?

EDIT: Further research seems to indicate that this is an issue with stacking contexts. I can recreate the correct behaviour when i use any properties which create a new stacking context, like `position : relative`, `opacity: 0.9`, `transform : scale(1)` . Although I still don't know why Safari behaves in this way.

Comment: My first instinct would be to try setting `overflow:visible;` maybe Safari has a different default behaviour to Chrome.

Comment: @musefan yes, i tried that, doesn't seem to work. I also checked the default browser styling, they seem to be similar for chrome and safari

Comment: I can report I've found this issue also with `button` in safari, and can confirm that (i) setting `overflow:visible` does not work, but `positive: relative` does.